# Why does this not generate an IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, string, indexing

So, this is probably a very silly question... But I just don't understand it.

I have a `String str = "AB"`, and when I call `str.substring(2)` it doesn't generate an index out of bounds exception... It doesn't return anything either, just "", which I guess it should...

But seeing as the string "AB" is of length two, doesn't that mean the max index is 1? So wouldn't calling the substring starting at the 2 index generate an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`? It generates an exception when you call `str.substring(3)`, which it should, just not for 2... which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: According to [**javadoc**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)), it only throws an exception *"if `beginIndex` is negative or **larger than the length** of this String object."* - the length is 2, the parameter (also `2`) is not larger than the length, so no exception is thrown

Comment: Heh, well I'm kinda new to programming and up till now, I only thought there was a Java API... Never realized that there was a Javadoc to explain how the methods work... Thanks for pointing this out though, I will be sure to check there next time :)

Comment: @LukeThistlethwaite No problem. Note that if you work with an **IDE** you can configure it such that it shows you the **Java-Doc** of methods and classes by just hovering them, very useful.

Comment: @Makoto It doesn't suprise me that you think your stuff is better. And it doesn't change the fact that this question is a dupe. Well and there are some more similar question about `substring(length())` being allowed, the proposed question was the first one I found.

Comment: @Tom:  Why would it?! ;)  In all seriousness, those answers go over *just* the Javadoc, but I add in a bit more detail and context from a mathematical perspective.  Y'see, `substring` always burned me in college, and relating it to math genuinely helped remove any ambiguity in its usage.

Comment: Uh, it is technically a duplicate, even if the answers here are better. By the way, @Makoto your answer helped me understand... Thanks. So, if the answers on this thread are better, should I still mark it as a dupe?

Comment: Here is another one: [Java - Why is str.substring(str.length()) an acceptable line of code?](//stackoverflow.com/q/33547529).

Comment: One more detail is that in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) there's an example of this specific case: `"emptiness".substring(9) returns "" (an empty string)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-), the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is only ever thrown...

> ... if `beginIndex` is negative or larger than the length of this String object.

What that translates to:  since `"AB"` is of length 2 and `beginIndex` is 2, there will be no IOOBE thrown due to the fact that 2 is not larger than 2.  You *correctly* observe that 3 will throw the IOOBE, because 3 is larger than 2.

It also helps to remember that `substring` goes from [n, m), where `m` is the length of the string.  If `n = m`, then you result in the mathematical interval [m, m), which [by definition is the empty set](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B0,%200)).  Producing an empty value from this set would be **correct** behavior.

Comment: I like that besides just explaining the behavior you also explain why it is meaningful and can be considered as **correct** behavior. I think that helps OP understanding the behavior even more.

Answer (score 6):

One way of thinking of the substring indexes, is as being between the letters. 0 is at the beginning and 2 is at the end. Like:

```
|  A  |  B  |
0     1     2
```

Each index selects the substring to the right of it. There is an empty substring at the end which is selected with index 2, so there are three possible results: "AB", "B", and "".

Comment: This is a pretty reasonable way to think about it, too.

Answer (score 1):

As you may notice :

```
String str = "AB";
str.substring(2);
```

this is valid according to the javadoc as `2` is not larger than the `"AB"` length:

> Throws:
>
> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex is negative or larger than
>   the length of this String object.

I wonder often the same question but it is the way that some JDK classes works with some methods relying on index.
For example  `ArrayList.add(int index, E element)`  `ArrayList.subList(int, int)` work also in the same way.

It is like if these methods considered a special slot after the last element.

In some methods as `ArrayList.add(int index, E element)`, it makes sense as when the index refers to the size of the list, it is for adding the element at the end of the list.

For example :

```
List<String> list = ...
l.add(list.size(),lastElement);
```

It is the single way to express it as specifying `add(list.size()-1, element)` will add the element at the before last place.

But in the `substring(int)` case, the use case is less clear since

```
String str = "AB", 
String subStr = str.substring(2);
```

will always return `""`.

But well, Java works in this way.

Answer (score 0):

subString method throws exception  - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

in your case you are passing single index and that will be treated as beginIndex
and hence it will throw IndexOutOfBoundsException only if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of this String object.

in your case beginIndex is 2 which is not larger than the length thats why you are getting empty substring

Answer (score -1):

The best approach to understand is to actually look at the source code (ctrl + click in Intellij over the method), it is self explanatory. Of course also to look at the javadoc as mentioned in other answers.

```
 public String substring(int beginIndex) {
    if (beginIndex < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
    }
    int subLen = value.length - beginIndex;
    if (subLen < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
    }
    return (beginIndex == 0) ? this : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

It is because your `beginIndex`is not negative.

According with Java Doc:

> Throws:
>   IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

If you set the parameters:

```
str.substring(0, 2)
```

It will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, according with the documentation.

Check: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)

Comment: I didn't downvote (and can't speak for the downvoters), but I **think** it's *probably* because you're talking about the 2-parameters version of  `substring`, but the question is about the [1-parameter version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))

Comment: Mmmm, maybe but my answer was based on question and how it could throw an exception. Anyway, there are fussy people hard to please.